# Sinch, presence info

Tags: sinch

Is there a way to get presence info of each sinch user (sinch sdk, user online/offline)?

for example, I would not want to make a voip call to somebody who is not online currently,
cause it takes too much time for Sinch to find out whether the call can be made or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to query for a user's capabilities before placing a call. Instead, an error specifying the user has no call capability will be returned when calling that particular user.